# Update MongoDB from DBRefs to manual references

Tags: java, mongodb

My Java-Spring-App is taking forever to load and after removing some `@DBRef` Lombok tags in my Java models, the objects were loaded lightning fast from MongoDB.

The problem I have now is: what to do with the already existing, slow loading data on my MongoDB in production?

Whenever I create "nested" objects they have and `_id` property referencing the subobject. But all my old objects have a `$ref` and `$id` property. 
How can I change this (preferably in Java - I'm using a `MongoOperations` object), so that my old objects also just use `_id`?

> Here a picture of an old db entry: [image: Old DB-Entry]
>   And here one of a new db entry - how can I change all old db entries to this
>   format? [image: New DB-Entry]